# How to use unique_ptr in constructor?

Tags: c++

Here I have tried to use unique_ptr in constructor. It gives the following error:

function "std::unique_ptr<_Ty, _Dx>::operator=(const std::unique_ptr<_Ty, _Dx>::_Myt &) [with _Ty=ABC, _Dx=std::default_delete]" (declared at line 1487 of "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\memory") cannot be referenced -- it is a deleted function

How can I achieve it?

StructCol.h

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#ifndef StructCol_H
#define StructCol_H

#include<string>
#include<memory>
using namespace std;

class ABCD
{
    public:
    std::unique_ptr<ABC> & n;

    ABCD(std::unique_ptr<ABC> & n1) : n(n1)
    {
        n = n1;
    }

    void print()
    {
        cout << n->no << endl;
        cout << n->text_c << endl;
        cout << n->no_c << endl;
    }
};

class ABC
{
public:
    string test;
    int no;
    string text_c;
    int no_c;

    ABC()
    {

    }

    ABC(string text_c1, int no_c1)
    {
        text_c = text_c1;
        no_c = no_c1;
    }

    void print()
    {
        cout << test << endl;
        cout << no << endl;
        cout << text_c << endl;
        cout << no_c << endl;
    }
};

#endif
```

Comment: remove `n = n1;`

Comment: This happens any time you do that assignment, not just in constructors.

Comment: `ABCD(std::unique_ptr<ABC> & n1) : n(n1)` - Who is going to own the pointer?

Comment: What is worse, you have reference to unique_ptr, not copy

Comment: why are people downvoting this question?

Comment: It needs to be `n(std::move(n1))`.

Comment: @AK_ Because question shaming is too easy among C++ programmers, I guess. This is a big reason SO frustrates me.

Comment: @EdHeal: Do you mean "who is going to own the pointee"? The pointers both have very clear owners.

Comment: Is pointee an English word?

Comment: Please inform the OED (Cambridge and Collins dictionaries as well)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A unique pointer represents at most *one* owner of its pointee. Therefore, a unique pointer cannot be copied. It can however be *moved*, which transfers the (potential) ownership to the target of the move and leaves the source of the move null (i.e. not owning anything).

Given classes `Xp`, `Xl` and `Xx`, each with a member `std::unique_ptr<T> p_;`, the following constructors all work:

```
Xp(std::unique_ptr<T> p) : p_(std::move(p)) {}
Xp(std::unique_ptr<T> p) { p_ = std::move(p); }

Xl(std::unique_ptr<T> & p) : p_(std::move(p)) {}
Xl(std::unique_ptr<T> & p) { p_ = std::move(p); }

Xx(std::unique_ptr<T> && p) : p_(std::move(p)) {}
Xx(std::unique_ptr<T> && p) { p_ = std::move(p); }
```

Only `Xp` and `Xx` have sensible constructors, though. They can be used as follows:

```
{
    Xp xp(std::make_unique<T>(a, b ,c));
    Xx xx(std::make_unique<T>(a, b ,c));
}
{
    auto p = std::make_unique<T>(a, b ,c);
    // Xp xp(p);  // Error, cannot duplicate p!
    Xp xp(std::move(p));
}
{
    auto p = std::make_unique<T>(a, b ,c);
    // Xx xx(p);  // Error, cannot duplicate p!
    Xx xx(std::move(p));
}
```

On the other hand, the constructor of `Xl` is weird and surprising:

```
// Xl xl(std::make_unique<T>(a, b ,c));  // Error, cannot bind to temporary
auto p = std::make_unique<T>(a, b ,c);
Xl xp(p);              // OK?!?
assert(p == nullptr);  // grand theft autoptr!
```